# split string in python with same delimiter

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which has "," in the strings and is also the delimiter. when i use

.split(",") the string is being split for every ",".

is there a way around this using which i can keep "," and still use it as a delimiter

Sample:

```
string = "hello","this is from melbourne, australia"
print(string.split(","))
```

result:

```
   ["hello","this is from melbourne", "australia"]
```

what i want:

```
["hello", "this is from melbourne, australia"]
```

Comment: How do you know what kind (split or keep) of `,` you have?

Comment: the , i want to keep is in quotes(""). This is part of a sub string

Comment: Yeah but what makes it special? If you can explain it in words why it splits at the first but not at the second there is a reasonable chance one might be able to explain it to a computer.

Comment: i have a string which i want to convert it into list. this string has "," separating the elements. some elements are descriptions, so they have "," within them. I want to keep the description part as it is and not split it by ,

Comment: Okay then you need some way to tell the computer what is a description and what is not. Not sure if that's possible. Probably not. Do you control the code that generates the string?

Comment: unfortunately no. i get this from the client and they put data with different template and delimiters which is making it hard to identify which is delimiter and which is in the description

Comment: Again: You're sample is definitely wrong because it doesn't work (throws an error) and does not return what you say it does. See also: [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean with "different template and delimiters". Please update ([edit]) the question and include the relevant details (and make sure the sample really works).

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "hello","this is from melbourne, australia"
print([s for s in string])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a tuple.

string = "hello","this is from melbourne, australia"

now try:
type(string)
This results in class 'tuple'

so, you can just do list(string), which results in tuple to be converted to a list.